# Some contacts are missing in iOS Contacts

Tags: iphone, icloud, ios, contacts

**How can I get back (some) missing contacts?**  Some contacts are missing in my iPhone's Contacts app.   They are available in my OS X's addressbook, both are linked by iCloud. Strangely, the contact name and information is appearing, when I receive a call or have a missed call. I don't have Facebook linked with my iOS contacts.

- iPhone 5s with iOS 7.0.4
- MacBook with OS X 10.8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution: in iOS, go to **Settings > iCloud**, put the contacts-switch off (choose erase from phone) and on again. After doing this, all of your contacts will appear after completing the sync (this can take some time).